# Do primitive data types have different bit patterns?

Tags: data-types

And if so, why do they have different bit patterns?

I read a book that said data types have different bit patterns and I was like "why do they have different bit patterns?"

Comment: recommended reading: **[Discuss this ${blog}](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6418/31260)**

Comment: What book? What language? There are implementations of languages that do some funny things with what amounts to a union in the data types themselves.

Comment: nevermind michael, i found the answer i was looking for(robert harvey's answer).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Signed Integers** can be represented using [four different well-know bit patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations).  They can vary in their bit patterns by [the number of bytes used to represent them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_(computer_science)#Common_integral_data_types), and [the way those bytes are ordered (endianness)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).  **Unsigned integers** have their own bit patterns that are different from signed integers.

Floating point numbers use an entirely different bit pattern representation.  [**Single-precision floating point**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) looks like this:

[image]

And [**double-precision floating point**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) looks like this:

[image]